# Digitally Sign PDF doc using eToken in c#

Tags: c#, cryptography, digital-signature

From last few week I am trying to Digitally sign Invoices using eToken by refering "Digital Signature for PDF documents"  by Bruno Lowagie (of iText Software). I have take help from the beek but facing issue when I try to integrate a signature file in the digital sign report.

Method

```
public void CustomerSignatureApp(String src, String name, String dest, Certificate[] chain,
    PrivateKey pk, String digestAlgorithm, String provider,
    CryptoStandard subfilter, String reason, String location)
```

but passing parameters are not matching.

It will be helpful if aye one give me hints to solve this matter.

Some of helping URLs are:

1. [Sign PDF with iTextSharp 5.3.3 and USB token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204940/sign-pdf-with-itextsharp-5-3-3-and-usb-token)
2. [How to Read a certificate from Usb Token(etoken pro 72 k(Java) )and attach to pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23243027/how-to-read-a-certificate-from-usb-tokenetoken-pro-72-kjava-and-attach-to-pd)

Comment: Please read the FAQ on how to ask questions on Stackoverflow. What do you mean with "take help from the beek"?

Comment: What the actual problem is? In order to get help you need to specify what you actually pass, provide the exact error message and its source (whether this is a compiler error or a runtime exception or ...).